# Change url in Route Config in Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, routeconfig

I want to change the address of a function (via RegisterRoutes).
I defined two routes.MapRoute but not working any.
I checked many examples and matched my code with them, but the problem still remains.
The real address is:
http://localhost:3127/account/register/3

I want my address to be changed to the following address:
http://localhost:3127/Reg

Should [Route("Reg")] be used at the top of the function for this?
Is a redirect required for this or not?
Do I need web.config settings to do this?

my action is:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Reg")]
    public virtual ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

my configuration in Register Routes:

```
   routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Register",
         url: "Reg",
         defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Register" },
         namespaces: new[] { "WebSite.Controllers" }
     );
        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Account",
          url: "Account/Reg",
         defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Register" },
         namespaces: new[] { "WebSite.Controllers" });
```

[image: routeconfig]

[image: error of call url address]

Comment: try clearing your cache once

Comment: @AdarshBaranwal    I remove cookie and call url by ctrl+f5, but the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this problem. I install IIS and change my code to below code. Then my address became OK.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Reg",
         url: "Reg",
         defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Register" },
         namespaces: new[] { "WebSite.Controllers" }
     );

[Route("Reg")]
    public virtual ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Needless to say, I put this piece of code at the beginning of the file RouteConfig
before all cases and after routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

Now, my url is http://localhost:3127/Reg everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RegisterController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Account()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Register",
    url: "Reg/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Register", action = "Account", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: I won't send id to action. you send id to call action and action is without argument. why?